# probability calculation question

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

It is known that in $p\%$ of cases, Joe helps Bill in his game of chess; In all the rest of cases Bill plays alone. When he does receive help, his probability of victory is $0.95$, and without help, $0.75$. It is known that if Bill lost a game , the probability Joe helped him is $3/13$. Calculate $p$.

Im pretty confident this task has something to do with conditional probability, but I'm not sure..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(\text{lose | help}) = 1 - 0.95 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{20}$
$\displaystyle P(\text{lose | no help}) = 1 - 0.75 = \frac{1}{4} $
$\displaystyle P(\text{help}) = \frac{p}{100}$
$\displaystyle P(\text{help | lose}) = \frac{3}{13}$
$$P(\text{lose}) = P(\text{help}) \times P(\text{lose | help}) + P(\text{no help})\times P(\text{lose | no help}) =$$
$$ (\frac{p}{100})\times(\frac{1}{20}) + (1 - \frac{p}{100})\times\frac{1}{4} = \frac{p}{2000} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{p}{400} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{p}{500}  $$

Applying Bayes' theorem,

$P(\text{ lose | help}) \times P(\text{help}) = P(\text{ help | lose}) \times P(\text{lose}) $
$\frac{1}{20} \times \frac{p}{100} = \frac{3}{13} \times (\frac{1}{4} - \frac{p}{500})$
Solve to get $p = \boxed{60}$.
Conditional probability questions are usually simple and fun to do, if you build [trees](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/prob_comb/prob_combinatorics_precalc/v/bayes-theorem-visualized)!

Comment: @some1.new4u thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome. Just thought it would look aesthetically better if the texts are not skewed so I added /text{}.

Comment: that's it...well done and thank you

Comment: really helpful ....

Answer (score 0):

This question is problematic because in chess, there is a nonzero probability of a game resulting in a draw.  **In order to answer the question, it is necessary to assume no draws occur.**  We will first operate under this assumption, and later explain why this is necessary.

Let $H$ be the event that Joe helps Bill, and $L$ represent the event that Bill loses the game.  Also, define the complementary events $\bar H$ and $W$, representing the event that Joe does not help Bill, and the event that Bill wins the game, respectively.  Then we are given that $\Pr[W \mid H] = 0.95$, $\Pr[W \mid \bar H] = 0.75$, and $\Pr[H \mid L] = \frac{3}{13}$.  The goal is to determine $p = \Pr[H]$.

To this end, we observe that $\Pr[L \mid H] = 1 - \Pr[W \mid H] = 0.05 = \frac{1}{20}$, and $\Pr[L \mid \bar H] = 1 - \Pr[W \mid \bar H] = 0.25 = \frac{1}{4}$.  By the law of total probability, we then have the unconditional probability of loss is $$\begin{align*} \Pr[L] &= \Pr[L \mid H]\Pr[H] + \Pr[L \mid \bar H]\Pr[\bar H] \\ &= \frac{p}{20} + \frac{1-p}{4} \\ &= \frac{5-4p}{20}. \end{align*}$$  But we also have $$\Pr[H \mid L]\Pr[L] = \Pr[L \cap H] = \Pr[L \mid H]\Pr[H],$$ or equivalently, $$\frac{3}{13}\left(\frac{5-4p}{20}\right) = \frac{p}{20}.$$  Solving for $p$ gives $3(5-4p) = 13p$, or $p = \frac{15}{25} = \frac{3}{5}$.

Now, if we did not assume that $\Pr[L] + \Pr[H] = 1$, we immediately run into a problem:  if there is a third outcome, say $D$, representing a draw, then for instance it is no longer possible to compute $\Pr[L \mid H]$ from the given information, because we are only given $\Pr[W \mid H]$.

Comment: P(H) = $\frac{p}{100}$, not $p$. So you answer will become $3/5 \times 100 = 60$!

Comment: $60$ and not $60$!